# how to send images which are in local folder in microsoft botframework sdk v4 using c#

Tags: c#, image, botframework

I  created a bot with Microsoft Botframework C# SDK V4 and it is working well. Now I want to add some images to that bot. I am using cards but cards are taking only url of an image. I want to send the images which are in my local folder. How can I make it work??

I already tried this with 15.handling attachments github repo(https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments). And while I am using the exact code in handling attachments github repo, I am getting the below exception stacktrace for inline attachments.

```
Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.’ at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.d__10.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.d__17.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.d__15.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass22_0. 
<g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.d__21.MoveNext()
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.AttachmentsBot.d__0.MoveNext() in 
C:\botbuilder-samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\15.handling-attachments\AttachmentsBot.cs:line 65
— End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.d__3.MoveNext()
 — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown —
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.d__13.MoveNext()’
```

How can I resolve this issue??

Answer (score 1):

The [15.handling-attachments](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments/AttachmentsBot.cs#L235) sample demonstrates how to read a local file, and attach it as a base64 encoded image:

```
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { GetInlineAttachment() };

private static Attachment GetInlineAttachment()
{
    var imagePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Resources\architecture-resize.png");
    var imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath));

    return new Attachment
    {
        Name = @"Resources\architecture-resize.png",
        ContentType = "image/png",
        ContentUrl = $"data:image/png;base64,{imageData}",
    };
}
```

Another option is to use the ConnectorClient's **UploadAttachmentAsync** api:

```
private async Task SendFile(ITurnContext turnContext)
{
    var webRoot = _env.ContentRootPath;
    var imagePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, "Resources", "BotFrameworkDiagram.png");
    var connector = turnContext.TurnState.GetValueOrDefault("Microsoft.Bot.Connector.IConnectorClient") as ConnectorClient;

    var attachments = new Attachments(connector);
    var response = await attachments.Client.Conversations.UploadAttachmentAsync(
        turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id,
        new AttachmentData
        {
            Name = "BotFrameworkDiagram.png",
            OriginalBase64 = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath),
            Type = "image/png"
        });

    var attachmentUri = attachments.GetAttachmentUri(response.Id);

    var attachment = new Attachment
    {
        Name = "BotFrameworkDiagram.png",
        ContentType = "image/png",
        ContentUrl = attachmentUri
    };

    var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
    reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);   
}
```

Comment: when I am trying with the first code snippet it is showing me "sorry it looks something went wrong" eventhough I added that image in my project resources folder. Can you please suggest me  How can I get  stack trace in exception along with default error message in sdk v4 using c#.

Comment: Make sure you've set the local file to 'Copy to Output Directory'.  You can get the exception stack trace by adding an OnTurnError https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments/Startup.cs#L95

Comment: Something else you can do is debug locally: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/

Comment: Thanks for the responses, Now i am getting stack trace along with default error message.

Comment: when I am trying with first code snippet after setting  local file to 'Copy to output directory' still it is not working. when I am trying with 'http url' ,it is working  but when I am trying with local path it is not displaying image. Do I need  to change anything else.

Comment: And also I tried 15.handling attachments github repo. In that also only internet attachment is working but inline attachment and uploaded attachments are not working. can you please suggest me what else changes do I need to make?

Comment: It is showing error at the line " await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);"  in handling attachments github repo.

Comment: @Mounika I'm not sure.  I would need to see the code you are using.  The above methods work as expected.

Comment: Hii, I am using the exact  code in handling attachments github repo and I am getting Exception StackTrace and I provided those details in question,  Please have a look. Do I need to make any changes  in handling attachments github repo??

Comment: I just downloaded the "15.handling attachments" sample again, ran it, and it works as expected.  Please email me at the address on my profile, and send the project you are using, if you need further assistance.  https://stackoverflow.com/users/86646/eric-dahlvang?tab=profile

Comment: I am also using the same handling attachments from github but it is getting exception. I sent you the project which I am using. Please have a look.