# Trying to combine Luis and attachement in C#

Tags: c#, botframework, attachment, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to customize the CoreBot example (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot) , so it can also receive images in addition to text.

While there are plenty of good documentation (below) and responses on stackoverflow, i am new to C# and have difficulties to combine several pieces of code with the C# syntax.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-3.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-receive-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-3.0
- [how to send images which are in local folder in microsoft botframework sdk v4 using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258245/how-to-send-images-which-are-in-local-folder-in-microsoft-botframework-sdk-v4-us)
- [Can a Bot receive image as message or attachment from a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488713/can-a-bot-receive-image-as-message-or-attachment-from-a-user)

On the code below, i am inserting this piece of code in the CoreBot :

```
var activity = stepContext.Context.Activity
            var reply = activity.CreateReply();
            if (activity.Attachments != null && activity.Attachments.Any())
                {
                var messageText = stepContext.Options?.ToString() ?? "this seems to be an image an i am not yet able to understand it";
                var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
            }
```

Below is the block of code in which i have inserted the "if image, then"

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ActStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {


             if (!_luisRecognizer.IsConfigured)
            {
                // LUIS is not configured, we just run the BookingDialog path with an empty BookingDetailsInstance.
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookingDialog), new BookingDetails(), cancellationToken);
            }

            var activity = stepContext.Context.Activity;
            if (activity.Attachments != null && activity.Attachments.Any())
                {
                var messageText = stepContext.Options?.ToString() ?? "this seems to be an image an i am not yet able to understand it";
                var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
            }



            // Call LUIS and gather any potential booking details. (Note the TurnContext has the response to the prompt.)
            var luisResult = await _luisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync<FlightBooking>(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken);
            switch (luisResult.TopIntent().intent)
            {
                case FlightBooking.Intent.BookFlight:
                    await ShowWarningForUnsupportedCities(stepContext.Context, luisResult, cancellationToken);

                    // Initialize BookingDetails with any entities we may have found in the response.
                    var bookingDetails = new BookingDetails()
                    {
                        // Get destination and origin from the composite entities arrays.
                        Destination = luisResult.ToEntities.Airport,
                        Origin = luisResult.FromEntities.Airport,
                        TravelDate = luisResult.TravelDate,
                    };

                    // Run the BookingDialog giving it whatever details we have from the LUIS call, it will fill out the remainder.
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookingDialog), bookingDetails, cancellationToken);
```

I have also added `AddDialog(new AttachmentPrompt(nameof(AttachmentPrompt)));` in the waterfall declaration as below

```
public MainDialog(FlightBookingRecognizer luisRecognizer, BookingDialog bookingDialog, ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
                : base(nameof(MainDialog))
        {
            _luisRecognizer = luisRecognizer;
            Logger = logger;

            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(bookingDialog);
            AddDialog(new AttachmentPrompt(nameof(AttachmentPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                IntroStepAsync,
                ActStepAsync,

            }));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }
```

The issue is that the code the piece of code I added is not doing anything.

As mentionned, i am a noob to C# and any suggestion or observation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try replcaing line  var activity = stepContext.Activity; with  var activity = stepContext.Context.Activity;

Comment: thanks @probin anand ! it does not show any error anymore .  I have edited my code in the question. However the bot does not react when user send an attachment.

Comment: If you are not using any attachment for now than you can remove that part of the code and go step by step

Comment: @probin anand, thanks. Actually i would like the bot to detect if the user send an attachment. Do you happen to know a good way to do this?

Comment: sorry brother i have not done much but this link would help "https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments"

Comment: @GuillaumeLabs It looks like you've mostly got this figured out. Are you still running into any issues? Is your bot not detecting attachments still?

Comment: @mdrichardson, thanks for asking! yes somehow the bot is not detecting attachement. I am wondering if this is because of the cascade structure of the code in main dialog https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised it even lets you compile with `Any()`. In my testing, Visual Studio threw build errors.

Change:

`if (activity.Attachments != null && activity.Attachments.Any())`

to

`if (activity.Attachments != null && activity.Attachments.Count > 0)`

---

The above answer assumes that the `activity` contains an attachment, but just isn't being caught. If `activity` doesn't even contain an attachment, there's something else wrong. In which case, please include your whole dialog or preferably, a link to your code/repo.

Comment: thanks again! i think i did not squeeze it in the right place within the code. It sometimes trigger the image message in response to text inputs